# DatePicker Value cannot be converted. when date format is dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am using WPF with MVVM pattern, I have a `DatePicker` in XAML like this:

```
<DatePicker Text="{Binding FCGene,Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedDateFormat="Short" />
```

In the constructor of the view and in the constructor of the viewmodel I set the culture like this

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
ci.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

When I pick a date like `13/02/2021` I got this error:

> "Value can not be converted"

right under the  `DatePicker` text box, I see the date in the text box in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` which is what I want.
I guess the problem is in the binding, in the assignment of the property, in my viewmodel, my property is this:

```
private DateTime fcGene;
public DateTime FCGene
{
    get { return fcGene; }
    set { SetProperty(ref fcGene, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you bind the wrong property. Your `FCGene` property is of type `DateTime`, but you bind it to the [`Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker.text?view=net-5.0) property of `DateTimePicker`, which expects a `string`, therefore, the conversion fails.

> Gets the **text** that is displayed by the DatePicker, or sets the selected date.
>
> ```
> public string Text { get; set; }
> ```

To make it work with the `DateTime` property, bind the [`SelectedDate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate?view=net-5.0) property instead.

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding FCGene, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedDateFormat="Short" />
```

If you want to bind the `Text`, then change your property type to `string`.

```
private string fcGene;
public string FCGene
{
    get { return fcGene; }
    set { SetProperty(ref fcGene, value); }
}
```

```
<DatePicker Text="{Binding FCGene, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedDateFormat="Short" />
```